# remove the wrapping of text widget or <div class=“textwidget”></div>

Tags: functions, widgets

When I write a quote in the text widget and displayed the text is wrapped as "My text...". I would like to remove the div and put simply "My text...". without using jquery.

For Example: Current output

```
<div class="container">
   <div class=“textwidget”>
       My text...
   </div>
</div>
```

Required output:

```
<div class="container">
    My text...
</div>
```

This is the actual code:

```
<div class="container">
    <?php dynamic_sidebar('text_show');?> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More than likely this is an issue with the [`register_sidebar()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebars) call in `functions.php`.

Look for `before_widget` and `after_widget`. The code below is the default usage.

```
'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
'after_widget'  => '</li>',
```

**Note:** This will alter all of the widgets within the sidebar, not just the TextWidget.

Comment: This doesn't actually work. The `div` we're talking about is inside that `li` element.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is probably better to do with css by applying a `display:inline;` style to the specific widget. something like

```
#id.textwidget {
  display:inline;
}
```

Where "id" is the id attribute of the widget. If you don't have one you should change your sidebar registration code to create one.

I don't think it is very likely that you will want such a behaviour on all your text widgets.